# Do I have to Install all dependencies every time in node?

Tags: dependencies, mean

Do I have to install dependencies for every `MEAN App` or I can just Install my
required dependencies globally ONE TIME and use them...
Curiously waiting for Response.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your apps use exactly the same versions in their dependencies you can install them globally.  But this is both rare and problematic.  As the "package.json" files change, so will your dependencies.  Also dependencies collected externally can change and what is global may not match between different app installations.

So depending on your circumstances, how often versions change, the development processes and sources for the apps, this might not be feasible.

If the issue is the download and seek times for dependencies, I have been using "sinopia2" which is a currently maintained enhancement of sinopia, a local NPM repo manager, which allows me to locally cache my installed node modules.  This can speed things up a little.  It also allows me locally serve scoped modules, so if I have a bunch of stuff shared among my apps I can put them in scoped modules for easy installation.

Comment: the problem is being a student i have to make alot of test apps and it takes a heck of a time for installing all the mentioned dependencies in package file. I just need a time saving method for these dependencies.
What if i just copy the "node_modules" folder (that have my required dependencies installed) in every app.????

Answer (score 0):

In every time you installed new package on npm you can install into globally
like [npm install -g ] or save [npm install -g  --save] package name into the package.json file.